# Trying to get user ID from Firebase (pyrebase) but error 'Invalid path: Path specified exceeds the maximum length that can be written (768 bytes)

Tags: python, firebase, pyrebase

I’m trying to store the user ID token inn a variable like this:
`token = user[‘idToken’]`

I’m doing this after the user has logged in with email and password. When i print the user variable it gives

```
{'kind': 'identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse', 'localId': 'cSZHkRIzGPWfuMmaZ93STFVvdr43', 'email': '1@1.com', 'displayName': '', 'idToken': 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEyODA5ZGQyMzlkMjRiZDM3OWMwYWQxOTFmOGIwZWRjZGI5ZDM5MTQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vc2Nob29sLXN1YmplY3QtZjdjZDQiLCJhdWQiOiJzY2hvb2wtc3ViamVjdC1mN2NkNCIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTU5ODAzNzUxMiwidXNlcl9pZCI6ImNTWkhrUkl6R1BXZnVNbWFaOTNTVEZWdmRyNDMiLCJzdWIiOiJjU1pIa1JJekdQV2Z1TW1hWjkzU1RGVnZkcjQzIiwiaWF0IjoxNTk4MDM3NTEyLCJleHAiOjE1OTgwNDExMTIsImVtYWlsIjoiMUAxLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJlbWFpbCI6WyIxQDEuY29tIl19LCJzaWduX2luX3Byb3ZpZGVyIjoicGFzc3dvcmQifX0.rZf3AYwhk7wvprE0c-VECBZ8vZyQ5LvwLNYECSWmaHDYNEFSGMRTDe_UD_cd28CyLlSKt-jNrnSUUI570E2LrLWUBf1Z5MdVAg5wExwDmM_AJqkQq8icqu1RXSYNar85i75oMfOEccQn6x8-UcXMtaVZhBCEFhN6mE6ZeW8CufFlu5kdf63Dw8GbyiNon9YVFwVjap7sEWcEfy3r4KJ8SscUarwuOtwJgybQcUpkgqRuPNTBhu6hcF7exDqIVC9mQzPtjQgWBsYAS1Ll8kkJaLJW9lYCd8__ybMgG-WJ7u_0_Q9t0zYVzzbk-7PFbttQC_QaNuMfzuGIKcypQ2eVMw', 'registered': True, 'refreshToken': 'AE0u-Nf0xpXPRjHUrIwCFOeSqVG709oIP5Yfjab7MRy8Eckk4Nx7jUGJGRHlMphFdVlKPwwK6_mE9ynAp-CnlVwM58dNHnAiD_4nzL7VgK-XX4vTBVbnAhNK-3r1T_sBfZEdbpV7a2UoNyE_4Kdi4CuRMWi96M96Xiv0VFH6ldy2mHJcSDd8p1MUVwV7eXOH2J195_4R8YiChqfKo5bQpfVuEZW9ICM36w', 'expiresIn': '3600'}
```

When my code is ran it gives the error in the title

How would i fix this?

Comment: Why do you need an `idToken` of lenght 1172?

Comment: @PatrickArtner if you look at what’s contained inside user the ID token is quite long. I’m going to try shortneining it with one of the answers to this post though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use the ID token as a path in the Firebase Realtime Database. Since the ID token is longer than the maximum allowed path, this is not possible.

Consider storing the ID token as a value, or using a hash of the ID token as the key (instead of the entire ID token).

Comment: To hash it would i just, for example, take the first 10 characters of the ID token for the key? Also what do you mean/ how do you store it as a value (i tried looking it up but i think I’m unclear on what to search for exactly)?

Comment: 1) That's tricky to say. As I've never tested how much entropy there is in ID tokens vs if there's a pattern. I'd use a common hashing algorithm, instead of trimming the string. 2) Make sure the value is in the data in the `set` call and not in a `child` call: `db.child("users").child("Morty").set(data)`

Comment: Oh right. I didn’t know what hashing was before this. So i assume i can just google a hashing algorithm to use

Comment: Thanks, i used the SHA hashing algorithm and it works now but it the new user ID token isn’t the same every time the user logs in, which i need to store all their data together. Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: ID tokens will indeed change over time, so you can't use them to identify a user. If you want to have a value that identifies the user consistently, use their UID, which is present at the key `localId` in your JWT.